# SQL Server Select that fills in rows, with length equal zero

Tags: sql

Have the following select giving me the data I want, but I want to expand it so that for every distinct defect a row is returned with a Product from the list with the correct length or zero if the row doesn't exist.

Here is the select

```
SELECT Product, Defect, sum(Length) AS Length FROM RejectTransaction  
WHERE  RejectTransaction.TranDate >= '20120620 00:00:00.000' 
AND RejectTransaction.TranDate <= '20120620 23:59:59.000' 
GROUP BY Product, Defect 
ORDER BY Product, Defect;
```

Here is the current output

---

ProductA  Dimension  560.00

ProductA  Film  40.00

ProductA  Handling  10.00

ProductB  Dimension  220.00

ProductB            Film    640.00

ProductB                Gel Coat    200.00

ProductC            Dimension   60.00

ProductC            Film    1160.00

ProductC            Mat Defect  810.00

---

What I'd like returned:

---

ProductA  Dimension  560.00

ProductA  Film  40.00

ProductA  Handling  10.00

ProductA                Gel Coat    0.00

ProductA            Mat Defect  0.00

ProductB  Dimension  220.00

ProductB            Film    640.00

ProductB                Gel Coat    200.00

ProductB  Handling   0.00

ProductB            Mat Defect  0.00

ProductC            Dimension   60.00

ProductC            Film    1160.00

ProductC            Mat Defect  810.00

ProductC  Handling   0.00

ProductC                Gel Coat    0.00

---

Have the RejectTransaction (Which data from above is from), Product, and Defect table if needed.

Sorry, dont have time to make this very pretty.  Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: You don't have time to make it "pretty", but you expect other people to take the time to help you?

Comment: Ok, called my bluff.  I haven't taken the time to figure out how to make it pretty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If as you say you have tables for product and defect, then LEFT OUTER JOIN should do the trick.

**Edit** 
The additional requirement to include only products, and defects, which rejected transactions referenced in the reporting period (and I'm also assuming that products and defects are independent axes) complicates matters, and here the refactoring of a CTE saves us time:

```
WITH frt AS
(
  SELECT rt.Product, rt.Defect, rt.[Length]
  FROM RejectTransaction rt
  WHERE
   rt.TranDate >= '20120620 00:00:00.000'
   AND rt.TranDate <= '20120620 23:59:59.000'
)
SELECT fp.Product, fd.Defect, SUM(ISNULL(frt.[Length], 0)) AS [Length]
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT frt.Product
     FROM frt
     ) AS fp -- Filtered Products
     CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT Defect
      FROM frt
     ) AS fd -- Filtered Defects
     LEFT OUTER JOIN frt  -- Filtered Reject Transaction
     ON frt.Product = fp.Product
     AND frt.Defect = fd.Defect
GROUP BY fp.Product, fd.Defect 
ORDER BY fp.Product, fd.Defect;
```

Full SQL Fiddle here : 
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e8b76/2

Comment: I'm using SQL 2008, I have no idea what a CTE is. I'm an engineer that grew up as a programmer, trying to make me a dashboard to track issues.   Thanks for the help, the above does what I want, with two exceptions, it returns all the products in my product table with the defects found for the timestamp and the length for unfound rows is NULL

Comment: A CTE is a Common Table Expression and allows for refactoring of subqueries etc. I've added the CTE version to the SQL Fiddle as well. The IsNull fixes the NULLs. My understanding was that you wanted a complete list of products and defects, hence the zeroes for missing rows in your expected output. Please advise on how you need the products and defects to be filtered? Note that you haven't posted any table schemas, so I've guessed.

Comment: I want a complete list of all products with all defects that were found within the time period.  So if my product table has 15 Products, but only A, B and C where rejected for the defects (showing in the RejectTransaction table) I only want to show product A, B and C instead of all 15 products.  The rest works perfect.

Comment: Changing the group by and order by from p.Product to frt.Product make it work as deisred except it gives me a Null as a product.   Also changed the p.Product in the first select to frt.Product

Comment: Is there an easy way to export schemas?

Comment: Perfect!  You rock!  Thank you very much.  Care to explain it so I can learn something?  If you have time.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: Glad I could help. Would be much appreciated if you could mark the answer as correct. CTE's are like a local or temporary view or table, local to the next query / update / insert statement (DML) - in this case we needed to repeatedly filter the RejectedTransaction table by a date range, but each time slightly differently - DISTINCT product, defect and then the SUM of lengths as an aggregate. CTEs saved us from repeating the filter over and over. See more here : http://facility9.com/2008/12/a-quick-introduction-to-common-table-expressions/

Comment: @nonnb I'm sorry, but it appears your fiddle here was lost during my server outage on sqlfiddle.com.  I had hourly backups, but it looks like yours was not caught in the last backup.  It appears that yours is the only one that was created (and published) during that window, so likely the only one lost.  My apologizes.